# How can I determine if a formula is out of margin?

Tags: math-mode, margins

I ask if there is a package that warns you when a formula in a line in math mode is out of margin (even slightly but still it is). When the formula is a little out of margin, I cannot recognize immediately in the pdf file..

Thank you

Comment: The geometry package has a showframe option.  If you aren't using geometry, there is the showframe package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put `\overfullrule=1pt` into your document preamble, LaTeX will put a bar next to any overfull boxes which will make finding your too-wide formulas in the PDF easier. As campa noted in a comment, there are also warnings in the output of LaTeX on the console although these can be easier to miss given the verbosity of some LaTeX processes.

Comment: There's a more direct way -- add the `[draft]` option to the `\documentclass`.  Unless someone has purposely turned that off in a package, this should put a black bar at the end of the overfull line in the margin.  (This will do some other things too, including just putting in the name of a file that is used with `\includegraphics`.  But LaTeX is almost always run more than once, so that shouldn't matter.)